# phpMailer not adding multiple addresses

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I got an issue with phpMailer and it is not sending to multiple addresses when using an if statement. If I hardcode the emails they work fine...

P.s. I have also checked the variables and the if statements and all are working correctly.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom('x@x.com', 'xxx');
$mail->addAddress($row['recipient']); 
if ( $row['recipient2'] != '' ) { $mail->addAddress($row['recipient2']); }
if ( $row['recipient3'] != '' ) { $mail->addAddress($row['recipient3']); }
$mail->addAddress('x@x.com'); 
$mail->addReplyTo('x@x.com', 'xxx');
```

**EDIT - NEW examples - bounty set:**

I tried the following script which should give me 7 addresses however I only get one. (The hardcoded one)

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom($from_email);

$mail->addAddress('test@test.com'); 

if ( $rows != 0 ) {
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i ++ ) {
        $row = clean_fetch_assoc($result);
        $mail->addAddress("test2@test.com"); 
    }
}

var_dump($rows);
var_dump($mail->getAllRecipientAddresses());
var_dump($mail->isError());

die();
```

Which returns...

```
int 6

array (size=1)
  'test@test.com' => boolean true

boolean false
```

As you can see `$rows` returns 6 so there is nothing wrong with the loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe `$row['recipient2']` is empty, you check this array `$row`

Comment: recipient2 and recipient 3 are not empty. I checked this with a simple IF != '' THEN echo $row['recipient2'] and it worked OK. It would appear to be some weird bug with phpMailer?

Comment: try with if ( $row['recipient2'] != '' ) { $mail->addAddress("'".$row['recipient2']."'"); }
    if ( $row['recipient3'] != '' ) { $mail->addAddress("'".$row['recipient3']."'"); }

Comment: you can show `var_dump($row);die;`?

Comment: This didn't effect the issue. I am revamping the question and setting bounty

Comment: you are adding the same email repeatedly in your loop... what's up with that?

Comment: Have you done any PHP error logging?

Comment: Which version of PHPMailer are you using? what does `var_dump($mail->to);` output for you?

Comment: As @Pamblam is pointing out, the function `addAddress` will reject any address that is already in the list of the recipient. See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/7b9fd0730946d56f4a194cf68bb9b75a8eb2563c/class.phpmailer.php#L803. You will see it by the `false` returned by `var_dump($mail->addAddress("test2@test.com"));`

Comment: my opinion is that @Pamblam might have a point. Try to change the second address to a non-valid email address. If your loop works correctly you will get an error message involving the faulty address. Please check https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php and search for functions `addOrEnqueueAnAddress`,`addAnAddress` you will see that email address are added only if the address not-exists in the array of recipients. Additionally in your second code example if `clean_fetch_assoc($result)` throws a `silent` error your loop goes away. So add address before that line.

Comment: So basically try this instead `if ( $rows != 0 ) {
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i ++ ) {
        $mail->addAddress("test2@test.com"); $row = clean_fetch_assoc($result);
        
    }
}`

Comment: I ran your code (with the edits `$rows = 6; $from_email = 'x@y.com';` and the removal of the line `$row = clean_fetch_assoc($result);`), and got a different result (two addresses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is not enought code shown to exactly and positively nail down your problem.**

But your `$row` strongly suggests that you're in the middle of a `while($row=$stmt->fetch())`, right?
We don't see anything like it in the code you show.

I think I have 99% chances to be right on this.
Your fix is to **"extract" your database data BEFORE** the PHPMailer part.

Get all your vars (Sender, From, FromName and an array of adresses... An array of BCC too? ).

**Finish your while fetch loop BEFORE** getting in the PHPMailer part, which shall not be included in a loop.

**THEN**, you can go on with your email construction.
Set your Body, AltBody and Subject.
Now is the time to loop into an address array.
 *(And don't call it $row!!)*.

By the way, your for loop declaration isn't as correct as you think:
 `( $i=0;$i<$rows;$i++ )` should be `( $i=0;$i<sizeOf($rows);$i++ )`.
Notice the sizeOf()?

This code that worked perfect for me:
I suggest you try it in order to get a confimation that PHPMailer isn't the problem.

```
// This array would be defined by you fetch loop.
$moreToAdressArray=["test1@example.com","test2@example.com","test3@example.com","test4@example.com"];

$endpointMsg->AddAddress( $clientLine['email'] );
for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($moreToAdressArray);$i++){
    $endpointMsg->AddAddress( $row[$i] );
}
$endpointMsg->AddBCC ($SENDER);
```

I've had 5 times the same email with this (adresses were different than ..@example.com - Doh!).
PHPMailer works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry for the late response I was away for a month. Works great. I was intiialising PHPMailer before the loops which I think it caused it to freak out. I am having more headaches with PHPmailer corrupting HTML emails but hopefully I can get it sorted! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

May this code will help you, plz change that as you need.

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, 'SELECT full_name, email, photo FROM mailinglist WHERE sent = false');

foreach ($result as $row) { 
    $mail->addAddress($row['email'], $row['full_name']);

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        break; //Abandon sending
    } else {
        echo "Message sent to :" . $row['full_name'] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row['email']) . ')<br />';
        //Mark it as sent in the DB
        );
    }
    // Clear all addresses for next loop
    $mail->clearAddresses();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first store your multiple emails like this

```
$this->db->select('ID, email, firstName, lastName');
$this->db->from('contact');
$this->db->where_in("ID",$Id);
$query=$this->db->get();
$res=$query->result_array();

for($i=0; $i<count($res); $i++){
  $toArr[$i]['email']=$res[$i]['email'];
  $toArr[$i]['name']=$res[$i]['firstName'].' '.$res[$i]['lastName'];    
}
$row["email"]=$toArr;
```

then addAddress

```
foreach($row as $v){
 $mail->AddAddress($v["email"], $v["name"]);
}
```

Comment: can you explain this?

Answer (score -1):

Your trying to send email to same recipients Multiple Times,To avoid this there is  condition inside AddAddress to remove same Recipients 
Kindly comment checkUnique($address) function inside AddAddress function.

You will find this function inside Class.phpmailer.php file

```
function AddAddress($address, $name = "") {
    /*if(!$this->checkUnique($address)){
        return;
    }*/
    $cur = count($this->to);
    $this->to[$cur][0] = trim($address);
    $this->to[$cur][1] = $name;
}

/** 
 * Added function for unique address Aug 29 Nitin
 *  @param string $address
 * */


function checkUnique($address){
    $flag= true;
    for($i=0;$i<count($this->to);$i++){
        if(empty($this->to[$i][0]) ||  $this->to[$i][0]==$address){
            return false;
        }
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($this->cc);$i++){
        if(empty($this->cc[$i][0]) || $this->cc[$i][0]==$address){
            return false;
        }
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($this->bcc);$i++){
        if(empty($this->bcc[$i][0]) || $this->bcc[$i][0]==$address){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
}
```